# What are the ideal set of tools to build a React.js client application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, refluxjs

We are starting a greenfield React.js project and are overwhelmed by all the options to use to "put it all together". There is Fluxxor, Fluxible, react-router, Baobab, Delorean, Marty, Reflux, just to name a few. We want to utilize the concept of unidirectional data flow and thus are not keen on using something like ember or angular in conjunction with React.

Our data will come from a Restful API we are building using Hapi.js so this is just a client application that will pull from the API.

Here are some other criteria we are considering:

- Relatively minimalistic - things are  changing so fast in this area
  that if there's a big shake-up with React  or if Relay suddenly drops
  next week we should be able to either adopt  the new way of doing
  things, or come up with our own solution to it.
- Well documented - speaks for itself
- Technically sound - not prone to race conditions, preserving uni-directional flow, no glaring errors, solid code base
- Active community - frequent checkins, responses to bug issues people post in git, etc

Any thoughts would be welcome!